# Minimal field of definition of the radical ideal $\sqrt{I}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings

Let $K$ be a number field, and let $I$ be an ideal of the polynomial ring $K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

Assume that $K$ is the minimal field of definition of $I$.

Let $L$ be the minimal field of definition of $\sqrt{I}$.

I can prove that $L\subset K$: Take $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma I=I$. Then $\sigma\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{\sigma I}=\sqrt{I}$, proving the claim.

But is $L$ always equal to $K$, or can the inclusion sometimes be proper?

Comment: This is easier to think about in reverse - you can throw in embedded components at nonrational points, which enlarges the field of definition but does not affect the radical. E.g. $J = (x^2+y^2-1)$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and for $N = (x - \sqrt{2}, y + i)^2 \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)[x,y]$, one has $\sqrt{J \cap N} = J$

Comment: @math54321: Thank you. I understand partly. I will try to rephrase your comment: You take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$. The ideal $J=(x^2+y^2-1)$ of $K[x,y]$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. The ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x-\sqrt{2}, y+i)^2$ of $K[x,y]$ is maximal, and you take $N=\mathfrak{m}^2$. So $\sqrt{J}=J$ and $\sqrt{N}=\mathfrak{m}$, and thus $\sqrt{J\cap N}=J\cap \mathfrak{m}$. You seem to claim that $J\cap\mathfrak{m}=J$, but I think this is false. Maybe it becomes true if we change $\mathfrak{m}$ a little, to something like $(x-1/\sqrt{2}, y-1/\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @math54321: Above I meant $\mathfrak{m}=(x-\sqrt{2},y+i)$ of course.

Comment: Well $J \cap \mathfrak{m}$ does equal $J$, as $(\sqrt{2})^2 + (i^2) - 1 = 0$, but yes any nonrational point like $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ works as well

Comment: @math54321: I see! I've just made a silly computational error. Still, why did you use $\mathfrak{m}^2$ rather than $\mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: You need to have some higher-order vanishing to actually get an embedded component (again as $J \cap \mathfrak{m} = J$). But you can take any $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal which is not $\mathfrak{m}$ itself

Comment: @math54321: All clear now. Thank you very much!